# Javascript array.find() only finds within first instance

Tags: javascript

I have the following object array:

```
var data = {};

data.type = {
    "types": [{
        "testA": {
            "testVar": "abc",
            "testContent": "contentA"
        }
    }, {
        "testB": {
            "testVar": "def",
            "testContent": "contentB"
        }
    }]
};
```

What I'm trying to do is find the value of `testContent` based on finding the object it belongs by searching it's parent and sibling:

```
/* within the data, find content where parent is testA and sibling testVar is "abc" */
var findSet = data.type.types.find(function(entry) {
    return entry['testA'].testVar === "abc";
});

console.log(findSet['testA'].testContent); /* returns string "contentA" as expected */
```

This works fine for first object but fails to find next object, giving error:

> Cannot read property 'testVar' of undefined

```
var findSet = data.type.types.find(function(entry) {
    return entry['testB'].testVar === "def"; /* Cannot read property 'testVar' of undefined */
});

console.log(findSet['testB'].testContent);
```

How else could I find what's needed?

[Here's a fiddle to test the output](https://jsfiddle.net/studiotime/q92omrfa/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
var data = {};

data.type = {
 "types": [{
     "testA": {
         "testVar": "abc",
            "testContent": "contentA"
        }
    }, {
     "testB": {
         "testVar": "def",
            "testContent": "contentB"
        }
    }]
};

var findSet = data.type.types.find(function(entry) {
    return entry['testA'] && entry['testA'].testVar === "abc";
});

console.log(findSet['testA'].testContent);

var findSet = data.type.types.find(function(entry) {
    return entry['testB'] && entry['testB'].testVar === "def"; /* Cannot read property 'testVar' of undefined */
});

console.log(findSet['testB'].testContent);
```

just check if your entry exist before testing his attribute.

Comment: Hmmm - I thought the whole point of `.find()` was to not have to do this - many thanks anyway